# What is the origin of this joke about matchmaking?

Tags: popular-culture, origins

The joke is told with references to Bill Gates and the World Bank, like so:

> I told my son, “You will marry the girl I choose.” He said, “NO!” I
>   told him, “She is Bill Gates’ daughter.” He said, “OK.” I called Bill
>   Gates and said, “I want your daughter to marry my son.” Bill Gates
>   said, “NO.” I told Bill Gates, My son is the CEO of World Bank.” Bill
>   Gates said, “OK.” I called the President of World Bank and asked him
>   to make my son the CEO. He said, “NO.” I told him, “My son is Bill
>   Gates’ son-in-law.” He said, “OK.” [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/7t6nny/i_told_my_son_you_will_marry_the_girl_i_choose/)

Many jokes are actually quite old and recycled so I suspect this one may have been refreshed with the contemporary references, but it's difficult to search for a previous version without those references. I'm looking for a more high-brow (i.e. older/more respectable) source and form of that joke, presumably devoid of the contemporary references, possibly with equivalent historical references.

Comment: I'm rather fond of joke etymology myself, but this is to my memory the first time we've gotten a question asking to do one.

Comment: Can't prove it yet, but if anyone else wants: at least as old as tsarist Russia shadchan/shadkhen-jokes? [Intermediate refs here](https://www.aish.com/j/j/51476077.html)